# I'm looking for wordpress theme that something interaction form

Tags: wordpress

If I'm a guest who find a home. I send a request my ideal home spec form to admin with 3rd party people who real estate have matching information of me. Then real estates are sending a proposal form to me with information that I wanted matching one with admin also. I'm not an expert in the area so I can't explain more professional. Any something like similar theme or plugin?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't know that. I'll do next time. Thank you for advising me.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question i suggest to use **contact form 7** plugin .

You can send the enquiry forms with the plugin and also you can send the values to a third party by using an action hook wpcf7_before_send_mail .

If you want an example code , let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[Use contact form 7 plugin](https://contactform7.com/)

For third party integration  - [click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-3rd-party-integration/#screenshots)